# How to remount /var over ssh

Tags: ssh, mount, partition, safety

I have a `/var` directory that sometimes gets too large for the partition it's on.  It would be beneficial if I could mount this directory on a larger partition.

I don't have physical access to this machine though.  Only SSH and similar remote access.

How can I remount `/var` **safely** on a machine that I don't have physical access to?

The only solutions I know of involve boot discs or `init 1`, so the popular directory isn't accessed during the transition.

Comment: do you "super user do" sudo acess in the remote machine? Can you do something like ssh -v root@somehost.. you may want to do something like sudo bash -C " excute some command...."

Comment: Which filesystem are you using for /var? You mentioned partition, but to clarify, do you mean a disk partition or an LVM volume?

Answer (score 4):

With only ssh (and su/sudo of course):

- mount the bigger disk on a temporary mount-point
- update `/etc/fstab` using the bigger disk **device** but using the mountpoint of the current `/var`, and with the existing disk device for `/var` in another temporary mountpoint (to allow recovering stray last-moment log messages).  Just editing `/etc/fstab` will not force the remounting.  And by the way, mounting it and writing to it ensures that you've made the filesystem, and have the device information consistent.
- rsync the current `/var` to the bigger disk (to reduce the amount of log-history loss)
- reboot, which will use the updated `/etc/fstab` to mount `/var` on the bigger disk.